# Standard Comments to Common Problematic Posts

Tags: discussion

In an effort to make new users feel welcome at AskDifferent, many users (including myself) have commented on problematic posts welcoming the new user to AskDifferent, explaining the problem, and providing ways to solve their problem. Most of the comments start with

> Welcome to Ask Different :)

and then have links to relevant help pages. Each one, although very similar, are not exactly the same. Some may include information and links that others don't, etc.

I thought it might be helpful to create a list of responses to common problematic posts for users to refer back to.

- The list would help new users to know how they should be posting
- The list would help users attempting to correct these posts do it in a respectful, but helpful/useful way
- It would allow the community to have a more uniform way of handling these scenarios

**I know many of these responses can be found on other meta posts but I wanted to consolidate all of them.**

These responses can be slightly altered to accommodate the specific Q or A.

---

Some example scenarios:

- Duplicate question
- Commend added as an answer
- Off topic questions
- Posts breaking the Be Nice policy
- Duplicate answers
- Questions with minimal information that need explaining

Comment: FWIW, I'm using the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) script; this both contains useful predefined comments and offers the possibility to enter your own for future use.

Comment: @Glorfindel Wow! Great find. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear supported on Safari :(

Comment: Personally, I use [Clippings Tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clippings/) that's compatible with the new Firefox Quantum browser.  Plus, it's works outside of SE for other sites as well.

Comment: @Allan You guys gave me an idea. What about an Automator contextual menu where you can add preset responses? It would allow it to be used in Safari and any other browser!

Comment: and @Glorfindel

Comment: I've never tried it with Tampermonkey on Safari. But an Automator menu sounds like a solid idea as well.

Comment: AutoReview with Tampermonkey on Safari does work. Quite good actually. But every update resets your custom comments…

Comment: @LangLangC Got it to work. Can you post your custom comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Although marked solved, please continue to edit and add your answers. The more the better!**

Here are a few I borrowed from the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) script. Things to note:

- I'm making this a community wiki, feel free to edit the comments if they are not clear or not [nice](/help/be-nice) enough.
- In the format below, they can be copy/pasted into the import/export functionality of the script (at least when you edit this post), so please keep it that way.
- The `[Q]` etc. indicate whether the comment can be used for questions [Q], answers [A], custom close reasons, edited questions, etc.
- The script will also start the comment with "Welcome to Ask Different!" if the author of the post is a new user.
- The `[tour]` link is a magic link and will automatically convert to a link to the [tour](/tour). More of these magic links can be found here: [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/373864).

---

#### [Q] More than one question asked

It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

#### [Q] Duplicate Closure

This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

#### [A] Answers just to say Thanks!

Please don't add "thanks" as answers. This *could* be an appropriate post if we were a discussion forum, but we're a Q&A site; answers must provide an answer to the question. Please take a moment to read the [tour]. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.

#### [A] Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

#### [A] Requests to OP for further information

This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more reputation, [you will be able to post comments](//$SITEURL$/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

#### [A] OP using an answer for further information

Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

#### [A] OP adding a new question as an answer

If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.

#### [A] Another user adding a 'Me too!'

If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

#### [C] Too localized

This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

#### [EQ] Improper tagging

The tags you were using are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//$SITEURL$/help/tagging)

#### [A] Not a discussion forum

This does not provide an answer to the question and is therefore deleted; please take a moment to read the [tour] – we're a Q&A site and not a discussion forum.

Comment: May I suggest to add the "source code" for all those comments? Maybe even in two forms: 1. as it would be pasted into the comments box (because of the links, incl.magic links) 2. as it would have to formatted for AutoReview? (Compare that to [Health](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/868/11231))

Comment: That's another option. I chose this format because it's easy to copy/paste it into the script *in one go*. Separate forms with source code are indeed useful for users who just need it for a single instance, but it will make the collection harder to maintain I guess. Other sites ([Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925/228959), [CS Theory](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1381/32711), [TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/117218)) have similar repositories. BTW, I'm fine with whatever format we choose for this.